# C - Using Recursion to Print Linked List

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I am required to write a function in C, that given a pointer to a linked list, will print out the elements in Python syntax: e.g. For the list consisting of 1,2,3,4 and 5, the function will print out [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

I have tried to write the code as follows:

```
struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int       data;
};

void print_list(struct node *list) {
    printf("[");
    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("]");
    } else {
        printf("%d", list->data);
        if (list->next != NULL) {
            printf(", ");
        }
        print_list(list->next);
    }
}
```

Output looks like this: [1, [2, [3, [4, [5[]

I understand that every time the function calls itself, "[" will be printed. is there a way to print "[" only when the function is called for the first time?

Comment: How about printing it _before_ calling the recursive function?

Comment: As in before calling void print_list?

Comment: Yes. Second option, add a flag to the parmeters that tells you if you should print a bracket

Comment: I would but I"m not really sure if I'm allowed to do it as this is for homework and I think the whole thing is meant to be printed within the function

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to change the parameters. I'm starting to wonder if this problem is even possible to solve

Comment: If recursion wasn't an actual *part of the requirement* (it might be if this is a practice assignment), don't do things like this recursive

Comment: Is recursion _required_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a wrapper function for printing braces. In between prints, call the actual recursive function, like this:

```
void print_list(struct node *list) {
    putchar('[');
    print_list_helper(list);
    putchar(']');

void print_list_helper(struct node *list) {
    if (list != NULL)
        printf("%d", list->data);
        if (list->next != NULL) {
            printf(", ");
        }
        print_list_helper(list->next);
    }
}
```

---

***Edit:*** As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166917/c-using-recursion-to-print-linked-list/45166983?noredirect=1#comment77302934_45166983) by Felix Palmen, a `static` variable is an option, but not the best. It works only when you call the function the first time. After that, the counter has to be reset, which isn't easy to do and makes the recursive function impure.

An example of the use of `static`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() {
    static int x = 0;
    printf("x In foo: %d\n", x);
    x++;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        foo();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
 $ ./a.out 
x In foo: 0
x In foo: 1
x In foo: 2
x In foo: 3
x In foo: 4
```

A static integer retains its value in between function calls. So, you'd be able to use it the very first time you call your recursive function, but you'd need to reset it every time you hit the base case.

Another example of `static`:

```
void foo() {
    static int x = 0; // initialization (done ONCE!)
    printf("x In foo: %d\n", x);
    x++;
    if(x%2 == 0) x = 0; // reassignment (done as many times as you like)
}
... // everything else is the same
```

This gives:

```
$ ./a.out   
x In foo: 0
x In foo: 1
x In foo: 0
x In foo: 1
x In foo: 0
```

Comment: Is it possible to solve the problem without creating a wrapper function or global variables?

Comment: Good idea, but the name `_print_list` is a poor one (since identifiers starting with an underscore are implementation reserved). Should be `print_list_content`

Comment: @M.Ng It is, with a static integer variable. I don't want to sound redundant, since [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45167070/4909087) answer already proposed it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks. I come from the world of python where private objects are prepended with an underscore :)

Comment: What's a static variable? and how would it help with the situation

Comment: @M.Ng Added an example to help you understand. Even across recursive calls, it retains its value.

Comment: I'm not really following the example, after void foo() executes, x is incremented to 1. But when the function is called again, won't x be reseted back to zero?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ see my comment on the other answer. Additionally, the function would only work a single time as expected this way. Your original idea is the only one feasible if it really **has** to be done recursive and you're not allowed to change the function signature.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Oh.. great point. Did _not_ consider that. Thanks for pointing it out. I've rolled back my answer.

Comment: @M.Ng On second thoughts, a static variable is not a good idea, because you need to reset it afterwards which is not possible.

Comment: @M.Ng Just to clarify, the _best_, most cleanest way to do this is using a wrapper. There's just no better alternative that doesn't involve jumping through hoops and creating spaghetti code.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it is *possible* to reset it e.g. in the tail of the recursive call. Still, it defeats the typical purpose of recursion, so I think your original answer is indeed the best one.

Comment: I still don't understand the difference between a static and normal variable. Might try again tomorrow when I'm not so sleep deprived

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yeah the wrapper one makes the most sense to me

Comment: @M.Ng After what Felix said, I will not advocate them for your use. However, if you wish to learn more, you can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean

Comment: @M.Ng inside a scope other than the file scope (so, e.g. inside a function), the default *storage duration* of a variable is *automatic*, this means it lives exactly as long as it is *in scope* during execution. Therefore: call the function again, get a **new** variable. You **can** give it *static storage duration* with the `static` keyword, this means its lifetime is for the whole execution time of your program (get **the same** variable with each call).

Comment: But even if the variable is the same one for multiple function calls, it just gets reset to zero which I dont get :/ ugh i lost the picture so I can't describe what i'm confused over

Comment: @M.Ng no, in something like `static int print_start = 0;`, the `= 0` isn't an assignment but an *initialization*. Initialization only ever happens once per lifetime of the variable, regardless of where it is declared. Assignment would look like `static int print_start; print_start = 0;` and this would indeed assign in each and every call.

Comment: Err, @M.Ng I added a second example. Hopefully this will clear it.

Comment: @M.Ng Fantastic, glad we could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a static integer.

```
struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int       data;
};

void print_list(struct node *list) {
    static int print_start = 0;
    if (print_start == 0) {
        printf("[");
    }
    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("]");
        print_start = 0;
    } else {
        print_start++;
        printf("%d", list->data);
        if (list->next != NULL) {
            printf(", ");
        }
        print_list(list->next);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to also set print_start =0 while printing closing bracket

Comment: Good solution. +1

Comment: If this is for practicing recursion, I don't think it's a good solution. Recursive functions typically aim to be *pure* functions, a global variable defeats that purpose. If on the other hand recursion isn't required, there are much better iterative approaches.

Comment: The if inside the outer else was theoritically useless.

Comment: I tried to give a solution with the least amount of modifications to the original solution. However, the solution that is pure is the only solution. This solution will work, however like @FelixPalmen it needs to be pure. I made it reset the counter to zero when it hits the end of the linked list so it works for OP's needs now.

Answer (score 0):

use global variable and change your code to

```
int count=0;
void print_list(struct node *list) {
    if(count==0)
        printf("[");
    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("]");
    } else {
        printf("%d", list->data);
        if (list->next != NULL) {
            printf(", ");
        }
        print_list(list->next);
    }
count++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional parameter which shows if it was called from outside or recursively. Most elegant way but will cost you some stack.